# CSS 3: Adding quote symbol to beginning of blockquote

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why this (also available live at http://jsfiddle.net/A2eTG/6/) renders a `"` symbol before the blockquote in Firefox but not Chrome/Safari?

```
blockquote
{
    padding: 0 60px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-left:55px;
}

blockquote:before {
    display: block;
    font-size: 700%;
    content: open-quote;
    height: 1px;
    margin-left: -0.55em;
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
}
```

The `blockquote:before` selector shows up in Chrome's developer tools but doesn't appear on screen.

What gives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like Chrome doesn't support `content: open-quote`. Try this instead:

```
content: "\"";
```

Comment: Chrome  does support `open-quote` and `close-quote` now.

Answer (score 48):

To help others who came across this and want prettier quotes than `"`, these are the codes for double open, double closed, single open, and single closed quotation marks respectively: `"\201C"`, `"\201D"`, `"\2018"`, `"\2019"`.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome supports `content` partially, and `open-quote` is not supported.

So what you can try is to use `content: '“';` The shortcut to print the `open-quote` in Windows is `Alt+0147` and if there is need for `close-quote` also then `Alt+0148`.

Answer (score 2):

See [Rendering Quotes With CSS](http://monc.se/kitchen/129/rendering-quotes-with-css) for more detail on this issue as well as how to localize the quotes for different languages.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be

```
content: '“';
content: open-quote;
```

That way browsers that support `open-quote` would use it and ignore the earlier `content` value, while browsers that don't know what `open-quote` is will ignore that line and use the first one.